# Do we count depending interfaces while calculating Efferent Coupling value for a package

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface

Should we count interfaces while counting Efferent Coupling metrics for a package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following Wikipedia page: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efferent_coupling defines Efferent Coupling as:

[Efferent Coupling] measures the number of data types a class knows about. This includes inheritance, interface implementation, parameter types, variable types, and exceptions.

So yes, if your class implements an interface, you should count that interface.